Identify maven test run inactivity gap
I'm running some test with maven. After the last test, before the output of results, there is a long gap of more than 5 minutes.
This increases the time to run the testsuite a lot.
I want to find out what happens in this gap to eliminate it.
mvn -B -f pom.xml versions:use-latest-snapshots clean test site -DgenerateReports=false -Dstyle.color=always -Dmaven.repo.local=./.repository -s ./xxx/setting.xml; EXIT_CODE=$?

[INFO] │  └─ ✔ testSomethingApi - 0.029 s
[INFO] // <-- 5 min gap
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[WARNING] Tests run: 403, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3

I enabled verbose output with
mvn -X

[INFO] │  └─ ✔ testSomethingApi - 0.029 s
[DEBUG] Closing the fork 1 after saying GoodBye.
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[WARNING] Tests run: 403, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3

but there is no output for the gap period. Apparently nothing happens, but obviously something is going on.
How can I find out what happens during this time period to hopefully being able to eliminate it?
Thank you!
